# QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000

Tags: qt, runtime, qstandardpaths

I am wondering if the above message is critical for the program's stability?

I got it when I ran my program, written in *Qt Creator 7.0.1* with *Qt 6.2.3*, in a terminal (/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -e sudo) on *Ubuntu 22.04.*

My Qt project's file is as follows:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += bluetooth

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11
...
```

The environment variable *XDG_RUNTIME_DIR* is set to */run/user/1000*.

I have never seen the above message before and do not know how and if it should be resolved. My assumption is that it may be related to my project's run settings in Qt Creator.

Comment: This happens if your env var setting of Qt5 platform themes may be a non-standard theme + your app is started as sudo (root  rights with UID 0): `echo $QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME`. This setting is normally found in the file `/etc/environment`. On X11 it may not cause problems but with Wayland your app may no longer start (just test it).